The final size of generated gif is much more than expected
I wrote a code for a bot which download a file, convert it to gif ( by moviepy ) and then it will send the final gif to the client. The problem is e.g the input is 5 mb and the result is 220 mb ! What should I do to compress it as low as possible?
This is my piece of code which downloads and make the gif :


@bot.on_message(at_state("VIDEO") & video)

async def download_video(client, message):

    downloading = await message.reply("⏳ *در حال دانلود فایل شما ...*")

    file_size = message.video.size

    max_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024

    if file_size > max_size:

        await downloading.edit_text("حجم فایل ارسالی بیشتر از 10 مگابایت است ")

    else:  

        response = await client.download(message.video.id)

        mime_type = message.video.mime_type.split("/")[-1]

        file_format = mime_type.split(";")[0]

        id = message.author.id

        with open(f"video-{id}.{file_format}", "wb") as file:

            file.write(response)



        await downloading.edit_text(f"""⌛️ *دانلود فایل شما با موفقیت به پایان رسید.

️ شروع ساخت گیف ...*""")



        # Context-Manager

        with VideoFileClip(f"video-{id}.mp4") as clip:

            resized_video = CompositeVideoClip([clip])

            resized_video.write_gif(f"video-{id}.gif", program="ffmpeg", fps=25)



        id = message.author.id

        await downloading.edit_text(f"""️ *گیف شما با موفقیت ساخته شد.

 شروع ارسال گیف نهایی برای شما ...*""")

        await bot.send_animation(id, f"video-{id}.gif", 60, 100, 100, "️ *گیف شما ساخته شد و نتیجه نهایی ارسال گردید.*")

        await downloading.edit_text("️ *گیف شما با موفقیت ساخته شد.*")

        await message.reply(f"""*جهت ادامه کار با ربات ،

یکی از گزینه های زیر رو انتخاب کن  *""",

InlineKeyboard(

    [(" ویدیو به گیف ️","1")],

    [(" عکس به گیف ️","2")],

))



        # Deleting

        time.sleep(10)

        os.remove(f"video-{id}.mp4")

        os.remove(f"video-{id}. gif")


Tags are incorrect (should better be something like: python,  zip, compression) , imports are missing from the piece of code, I can not even see a try to zip the file(s). Just googling 1 min to find info about : https://stackoverflow.com/q/25448923/461212

Tags are incorrect (should better be something like: python,  zip, compression) , imports are missing from the piece of code, I can not even see a try to zip the file(s). Just googling 1 min to find info about : https://stackoverflow.com/q/25448923/461212
